# How to move containerd data directory to another location on ubuntu?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

trying copy data from the pod and got

```
failed to copy: write /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1/data: no space left on device
```

My `/var` is full and I wanna change the container's root directory, is there a way to change the directory from `/var/lib/containerd/`?

Answer (score 3):

you will need to change the path in the [/etc/containerd/config.toml](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/ops.md#base-configuration)

```
version = 2

# persistent data location
root = "/var/lib/containerd" #your_free_path_here
```

make sure to restart `containerd`

```
sudo systemctl restart contained
```

to check the container version

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide | grep containerd
```

[environment-container-runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/)

[containerd-as-a-kubernetes-container-runtime](https://www.nocentino.com/posts/2021-12-27-installing-and-configuring-containerd-as-a-kubernetes-container-runtime/)

Comment: tnx a lot, it`s worked.